# Modify caption for a longtable series

Tags: captions, longtable

I need to create a book where tables are counted:

Table 1: "caption text"

Table 2a: "caption text"

Table 2b: "caption text"

Table 3: "caption text"

...

Is there a simple solution for this?
I am using Komascript (`scrbook`) and `longtable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a one off you don't need to define any specific counters just

```
\begin{longtable}..
\caption{caption of table 1}
\end{longtable}
```

then

```
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}a}


\begin{longtable}..
\caption{caption of table 2a}
\end{longtable}


\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}b}


\begin{longtable}..
\caption{caption of table 2b}
\end{longtable}


\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}


\begin{longtable}..
\caption{caption of table 3}
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this clean example (answer1). I was trying something close but a bit more complicated:

`\begin{longtable}..
\caption{caption of table 1}
\end{longtable}`

`\addtocounter{table}{-1} 
\renewcommand{\thetable}{2\alph{table}}`

`\begin{longtable}..
\caption{caption of table 2a}
\end{longtable}`

`\begin{longtable}..
\caption{caption of table 2b}
\end{longtable}`

`\addtocounter{table}{2} 
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}`

`\begin{longtable}..
\caption{caption of table 3}
\end{longtable}`

while this is working it was a bit confusing and created issues when it was on a deeper chapter inside the book (if the first table is for instance 10th and I wanted to compile the chapter alone I was getting errors).
This is why the first answer is more clean.